# Node-red hangs when sending fast node.send(msg)

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am struggling with a problem in a node configuration for node-red.
I have made a node, which have an input and an output. Every time the input is getting a payload message of any type, it performs a reading of a file, and throw that content out on the output.
The problem is, that when i am sending an input signal with an interval of 0.01 sec, node red flow editor (web interface) hangs! I have figured out that it is the

```
node.send(msg)
```

that is causing the problem, because if a just put the message on

```
console.log(msg)
```

Everything works fine.

When node-red hangs, the only thing I can do to make it "alive" again is the delete the flow json file.

I get this error:

```
28 Jun 08:22:43 - [red] Uncaught Exception:
28 Jun 08:22:43 - Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open
```

Is there a limitation for node-red opening, reading and closing files quickly?

here is my .js source code:

```
   node.on('input', function(msg){


        fs.readFile(path.location,(err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if(name === 'Mains current') {
                data = {payload: data/1000*(-1), topic: msg.topic};
            }
            else {
                data = {payload: data/1000, topic: msg.topic};
            }
            node.send(data);
        })        
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
I made a busy flag;

```
 var busy = false;
 node.on('input', function(msg){


        if (busy){
            console.log('busy');
            return;
        } 
        busy = true;
            fs.readFile(path.location,(err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                if(name === 'Mains current') {
                    data = {payload: data/1000*(-1), topic: msg.topic};
                }
                else {
                    data = {payload: data/1000, topic: msg.topic};
                }
                node.send(data);
                busy = false;

            })        
    })
```

Comment: This does mean that incoming messages that arrive while the node is reading a file will be lost.  Also it's bad practice to not flow the incoming message through a node that has both input/output. You should update msg.payload and call `node.send(msg)` rather than just copy the topic over to prevent loss of any other fields in the msg object. Also throwing the err will cause Node-RED to crash